# Train NER with Custom Training Data

Tags: nlp, training-data, named-entity-recognition

I am new to NLP and started with Spacy. I want to train NER with custom data and I am looking for free tool that can be used for Annotation.
Please suggest if you are using any open-source and User-friendly tool

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can start labeling with:

- https://labelstud.io, or
- https://github.com/doccano/doccano

The Spacy team also has the Prodigy (https://prodi.gy/), which could be freely used in academia.

Comment: Thank you. This Helped. I am able to annotate the document

Comment: You are welcome. btw You can upvote the answer for others indicating its usefulness.